# how to see if millions of users have crossed path using postgis

Tags: postgis

I have GPS points of a million users, and I want to select users who have crossed path; meaning that they have points within a distance threshold (50 meters) and within time threshold (15 minutes). Each user has on average 80 points during multiple weeks, and each point has attributes:

> lat, lon, arrival_time, leave_time

This comparison needs to be done for any possible combination two users out of a million. I am building cartesian table of all the points of each pair of users, which makes the processing huge. Can anyone suggest a method to compare only points that are temporally or spatially close?
I am hoping to achieve so, using postgis and python.